# How get attribute of link in callback fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

There is a code with a settings fancyBox window:

```
$(".play").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        maxWidth: "90%",
        padding: 0,
        autoCenter: false,
        scrolling: 'no',
        fitToView: false,
        beforeLoad: function () {

 }
```

And HTML code with a link `.play`:

```
<a href="#" id="2">Show</a>
```

How to get attribute `id="2"` in callback  `beforeLoad:`?

I tried `this.id`

Comment: Try $(this).attr('id');

Comment: That gives me result: underfined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is: `$(this.element).attr("id")`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
 var id=$('a').filter(function() {
   return $(this).text().trim() == "Show";
}).attr("id")
```